# Can a local homeomorphism have an injective continuous non-open section?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be topological spaces.  Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be an *injective* continuous map.  Let $r:B\rightarrow A$ be a local homeomorphism which is also a retraction for $f$, that is $r\circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$.

Is there a proof that $f$ must be open?
Is there a counterexample?

**EDIT:** Thanks to Ruy for the answer. So $f$ must be open.  This implies:

Any section $f$ of a local homeomorphism such that $f$ is injective and countinuous must be a homeomorphism onto its image.

Equivalently, every injective continuous map with a local homeomorphism as a retraction is a homeomorphism onto its image.

This question came up while I thought about étale groupoids and the answer is a helpful technical result there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $f$ must be open.

To prove it,  pick any open subset $U\subseteq A$ and let $b\in  f(U)$.  We need to prove that $b$ is an interior point of $f(U)$.

Let $\Omega $ be an open neighborhood of $b$ such that $r(\Omega )$ is open and $r$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $\Omega $ to
$r(\Omega )$.

Write $b=f(a)$, for some $a\in  U$, so that $a=r(b)\in r(\Omega )$.

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ such that $f(V)\subseteq \Omega $, and we may clearly suppose
that $V\subseteq r(\Omega )\cap U$.

Since
$$
  r: \Omega \to r(\Omega )
  $$
is a homeomorphism, we may consider the inverse of the restriction of $r$ to $\Omega $, which we will denote by $r'$.

For every $v$ in $V$, observe that  $f(v)\in \Omega $, and
$r(f(v))=v$, so $f(v)=r'(v)$.  This shows that $f$ coincides with $r'$ on $V$, and hence
$$
  b=f(a) \in  f(V)= r'(V) = r^{-1}(V)\cap \Omega ,
  $$
which is open and contained in $f(U)$.   QED